# DeviseLdapAuthenticatable: Can't login using either username or email (no such column users.login error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've set up a new application with devise and devise ldap authenticatable. Then I've followed their Wiki How-To login using either email or username. Now I get "SQLException: no such column: users.login" error.

I've tried everything I could find on stackoverflow and nothing worked.

application_controller:

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :password])
  end
```

user.rb

```
  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions) 
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(userPrincipalName) = :value", {value: login.strip.downcase}]).first
  end
```

devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [:login]
```

I want my users to sign in using either their email(which in my case is userPrincipalName) or username. But the only thing I get when I try to login is this no column error.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that you have no `login` column in your schema for the `users` table. Devise only generates an "email" field that serves as login by default.

You can add it easily via

```
rails g migration AddLoginToUsers login:string:index
rails db:migrate
```

You can then remove the `attr_accessor :login` part as the `login` field will automatically be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this breaks my Devise::LDAP::Adapter call, which I'm using to get several attributes from my LDAP-Server. Now it says no method each for nil:nilclass.

Comment: I don't want that login column in my users table. What I exactly want is, that users are able to login(via this virtual attribute) using their username OR email. It shouldn't say: no login column, because it's only a virtual attribute which uses either username or userPrincipalName(in my case)